# HasColumnName() with JSON property in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, jsonb, asp.net-core-8

I recently upgraded a project to EF Core 8 in order to take advantage of recently added JSON type capabilities.  The project is an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API written in C#. The database is PostgreSQL 16.

EF Core thinks that I am defining a property twice and I think I know why, but I don't know how to get around it.

I use Pascal casing in my model names and property names.

```
public class Article
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? DocId { get; set; }
    public string? ArticleBody { get; set; }
    public List<PointGeometry>? PointArray { get; set; }
    public PointGeometry? Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

Below I'm defining the JSON properties according to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns).  But I also want to use snake_casing in the actual database table names and column names. So I'm defining the column names in the `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(a =>
    {
        a.ToTable("article");
        a.Property("Id").HasColumnName("id");
        a.Property("DocId").HasColumnName("doc_id");
        a.Property("ArticleBody").HasColumnName("article_body");
        a.Property("PointArray").HasColumnName("point_array");
        a.Property("Geometry").HasColumnName("geometry");
        a.OwnsMany<PointGeometry>(x => x.PointArray, y => y.ToJson());
        a.OwnsOne<PointGeometry>(x => x.Geometry, y => y.ToJson());
    });
}
```

This is working fine for all columns and properties except for those last two that hold JSON data. The `point_array` and `geometry` columns are of jsonb type.

Method from my repository class to run a query:

```
public async Task<List<Article>> GetAsync(string where, List<string>? outFields = null, int? offset = null, int? limit = null)
{
    string offsetLimit = limit != null && offset != null ? $" offset {offset} limit {limit}" : "";
    FormattableString query = $"select * from article where {where} {offsetLimit}";

    var articles = _context.Article.FromSql(query).ToList();

    return articles;
}
```

When EF Core queries it throws this exception:

> The property or navigation 'Geometry' cannot be added to the 'Article' type because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on the 'Article' type.

I suspect EF Core is trying to define `Geometry` a second time when I call the `OwnsOne()` method when it has already defined it once when I call the `HasColumnName()` method two lines prior.

Is there another way to explicitly define the column name in camel case on a property that is mapped to a JSON type?

**UPDATE:** As suggested by @GertArnold I renamed the properties in my  model class as follows:

"Geometry" -> "geometry"

"PointArray" -> "point_array"

And it runs queries without errors now.  This work-around does the job but I'd rather not break convention with these property names just to avoid confusing EF Core.  I'm still looking for a solution that doesn't break the naming convention for jsonb properties that need explicit column renaming and defining as a JSON type.

Comment: @Dai sorry that was a typo.  I'm running postgres v16.  I updated the post

Comment: *I suspect EF Core is trying to define Geometry a second time* -- That could easily be verified by giving the column "geometry" another name temporarily.